# Magento2: How to add a text between swatch configure and swatch attribute name?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, swatches

I am having trouble while creating a module that add a text between swatch configure and swatch attribute name load by default, I want to add it only on a specific swatch if I have more than one. And what if it an `input`. How Can I do that? 
For exmaple: we have
[attribute name] [attribute configure] 
I want to add a text between them 
[attribute name] [text] [attribute configure] 
How can I do this, thanks 
[image]

Comment: Do you want to load it by default OR on On click swatches? And also please add screen here what exactly you expect?

Comment: I want to load it by default, but really do not know how to do it

Comment: Can you please add screenshot what do you want OR on which page?

Comment: @RaviSoni I just add it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add below code in **swatch-renderer.js**

Override this file in your custom theme and add custom code in below funciton.

> /vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js

```
_init: function () {
    if (_.isEmpty(this.options.jsonConfig.images)) {
        this.options.useAjax = true;
        // creates debounced variant of _LoadProductMedia()
        // to use it in events handlers instead of _LoadProductMedia()
        this._debouncedLoadProductMedia = _.debounce(this._LoadProductMedia.bind(this), 500);
    }

    if (this.options.jsonConfig !== '' && this.options.jsonSwatchConfig !== '') {
        // store unsorted attributes
        this.options.jsonConfig.mappedAttributes = _.clone(this.options.jsonConfig.attributes);
        this._sortAttributes();
        this._RenderControls();
        this._setPreSelectedGallery();
        $(this.element).trigger('swatch.initialized');
    } else {
        console.log('SwatchRenderer: No input data received');
    }
    this.options.tierPriceTemplate = $(this.options.tierPriceTemplateSelector).html();
    if ($(".swatch-attribute.color")[0]){
        $('.swatch-attribute.color').after('<span>Some text</span>');
    }
},
```

Here **'Some text'**

Now color is your specific swatch code. "You can add your attribute code here"

Please check this.

Comment: and what if in a product there are many swatches how can I choose a specific  swatch attribute and add some text to it. I can understand your code however, it work with every swatch attribute, but not with an individual swatch attribute

Comment: Check now I have updated my code

Comment: Oh thanks, I want to ask what is number 0 mean in this line `if ($(".swatch-attribute.color")[0])`

Comment: I add your code to my module however, it not display next to swatches attribute name it display under them

Comment: Oh. here I come to solution with your code. `$('.swatch-attribute.color > .swatch-attribute-label').after('<span>Some text</span>')` it will place next to swatches attribute name. Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome :). Can you please click on UP arrow & and mark as correct answer if it helps you.